# How to combine mutiple Lottie animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, lottie

Is there a way to combine multiple Lottie animations into a single one?
I tried https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-js but failed.
Above lib offers good enough API to manipulate existing elements, but doesn't allow to combine aniamtions.
Are there any other javascript libraries that may achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, just a bunch of Lottie animations. I'm trying to merge or arrange them like a timeline via code. Right now I'm just showing and hiding those animations based on a timer.
What I want is to combine them into a single Lottie.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play animations in a sequence, one after the after when they finish you could use [Lottie-Interactivity](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-interactivity). One of the modes allows you to play animations in a sequence, even loading them from a URL so you won't have to stick the animations together manually, heres a section from the LottieFiles website explaining how to set it up:
https://lottiefiles.com/interactivity#chainLoadExample

Using that library your setup would look like this:

```
LottieInteractivity.create({
    player: '#chainLoadPlayer',
    mode: 'chain',
    actions: [
    {
        state: 'autoplay',
        transition: 'onComplete',
        path: 'URL'
    },
    {
        state: 'autoplay',
        transition: 'onComplete',
        path: 'URL'
    },
    {
        state: 'autoplay',
        transition: 'onComplete',
        path: 'URL',
        reset: true
    }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam for replying, I intend to export the sequenced animation as a video (on the frontend) not just display it. Also there may be some overlapping animations also.

Could you tell me, what properties need to be manipulated if I need to offset the animation by n seconds?